# Eclipse Indigo 3.7 - GAE - An error occurred while trying to sign in 400

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I've just tried to deploy my test app to GAE but the error dialog opens as

> " An error occurred while trying to sign in 400. See the error log for
>   more details"

I am not pretty sure what that error means because all things seems to be fine as I have google account and I have my GAE app ID; But this eclipse error is quite weird :( Please give me some detailed advices where to look at and how to fix it

The log says...

> !ENTRY com.google.gdt.eclipse.login 4 0 2012-01-03 06:42:25.000
>   !MESSAGE Could not sign in !STACK 0
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:209)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.AbstractOAuthGetToken.execute(AbstractOAuthGetToken.java:64)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.authorizeStep1(GoogleLogin.java:535)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:416)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:379)
>     at
>   com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution$1.mouseUp(LoginTrimContribution.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:219)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

P.S.
I have Eclipse Helios 3.6 installed and its GWT GAE deploy throws the same error :( Why can it be?

Comment: Any tips please. Where to start looking ?

Comment: I'll be glad any suggestion what should I do in this kind of eclipse error? And what means "See the error log for more details"?

Comment: Just FYI, the error log is in `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`, you can open it with notepad.

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my question with log details

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4969), this occur when your computer have incorrect date/time/timezone. Please check your setting.